# String written in different fonts

Tags: c#, xaml, button, fonts, uwp

In my UWP app I'm trying to add a `Button` which has written on it an icon of the Segoe MDL2 font family and today's date, the problem is that I cannot show both the icon and the text due to the fact that they belong to different font families, is there a way to show both?

The button is defined like this in the XAML code:

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content=" " FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"  AutomationProperties.Name="Favorite" />
```

And the code I use to update the `content` property of the button is this:

```
button.Content = "&#xE787;" + date;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With WPF the trick is to use a `TextBlock` as your button's content. I am assuming this also works in UWP, but I am not 100% sure.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run FontFamily="Arial">Hello </Run>
            <Run FontFamily="Courier New">Mr. Bob</Run>
            <Run FontFamily="Arial">, you have foo.</Run>
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

With the `TextBlock` you can add multiple `Run` objects to explicitly define different formats for each section of text.